# I only want to buy two knives, which two types to get?

Tags: equipment, knives

I plan on cooking pretty simple foods and will need a knife for things like stir fry, the occasional meat dish, soups, casseroles, basically just standard fare. What brand and type will get me good value and all-purpose use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What knives are "required" for a serious home kitchen?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/184/what-knives-are-required-for-a-serious-home-kitchen)

Answer (score 9):

I recommend that you get a chef's knife *or* a [santoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santoku) (both are general purpose knives), and a paring knife.  For most western cooks who will be learning from western examples, the chef's knife may be the better choice.

These two knives will cover most needs.  See:

[Which knife is best for somone just learning to cook?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35453/which-knife-is-best-for-somone-just-learning-to-cook)

If you were to add a third knife, a serrated bread knife can be very useful for certain tasks (like bread, and perhaps unexpectedly, chopping chocolate).

Comment: This is the right answer. I'd recommend getting a larger (~4 inch) paring knife, because I think they have more utility, but those are the only two you really need.

Comment: How much should I expect to pay?

Comment: If you are only getting two, I'd say get a medium sized serrated paring  knife along with a Chefs.  Also don't forget a steel or means of sharpening.

Comment: @grayQuant Somewhere between $20 and $250, assuming you are in the US.  There are huge variants in knife pricing, not all of which are quality related.  elsewhere in the world, i cannot even speculate.

Comment: If you're only getting two, ignore price, go to a good kitchen store and see what feels good in your hand and buy it. It's 2 knives you'll probably be using daily for a very, VERY long time.

Answer (score 1):

I have three: a santoku style all-purpose knife, a long bread knife (also good for grating/scraping), and a cleaver since I often buy meat in large chunks.

Brands aren't really important unless they offer something unique that you find desirable, but do spend more than $10 or you'll likely end up with something that won't last. A good knife is one that feels comfortable and has a decent rep. If you can satisfy that, then just like a guitar, it will get better the more you use it.

Also, get a honing steel to keep it in shape.

Answer (score 0):

Just a Chef knife, and a pairing knife. However, make sure that you love working with them. I recommend that you get 2 or three of each, bring them home, and experiment on a potato or cucumber. then return the un-easy ones, and keep your favorite grip friendly ones. good luck.

Comment: I imagine some stores won't be wild about you returning a used knife; you can often make do with just feeling the weight of it in the store, how the handle fits in your hand, and imagining using it.